# Gremlin query to combine edge with property

Tags: gremlin

I have a data schema where users can review products. `user` and `product` are vertices, and `reviews` is a **MANY2MANY** relation between `users` and `products`. `reviews` has edge properties such as title and body.

I want to write a query to get all reviews for a product, as well as the users that wrote the review. I can get the reviews using the following, but I don't know how to add all the user properties.

```
g.({product}).inE("reviews").values()
```

How can I get user information per review as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
l = g.V(pvid).                          // start with a product vertex id
      inE("reviews").as("r").           // label the review edges
      outV().as("u").                   // label the users
      select("r", "u").by(valueMap()).  // properties map
      toList()                          // iterate traversal into a list
```

This will return a list of maps. Each map will have 2 keys, `r` and `u`, corresponding to the `select("r", "u")` step. Then the value of the `r` in the map are the properties for the review. Similarly the value of the `u` in the map are the properties for the user.

Related documentation

- [As step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#as-step)
- [ValueMap step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step)

Comment: This is super helpful already. By chance, do you know how you could make it so that  there wasn't a record for each combo. Like all the "u"s were nested under their respective "r"? For reference, mine looks more like this: `g.V().hasLabel('org').as('o').outE('orgStore').inV().as('s').select('o','s').by(valueMap())` but instead of getting back the same 'o' multiple times for every 's', I'd like one instance of 'o' with all of it's 's's underneath.